В 5 версии gulp, при копировании изображений, на выходе получаються битыми
Когда я хочу скопировать изображение с исходного кода, в папку build. На выходе я получаю
битые изображения.
Вот стандартный код таски:
export const images = () => {
    return gulp
        .src(path.src.images)
        .pipe(plumber(plumberNotifySettings("IMAGES")))
        .pipe(newer(path.build.images))
        .pipe(debug({ title: 'Обработка изображения:' }))
        .pipe(imagemin(imageminOption))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.images))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
};

в логах пишет что всё нормально обработано, ног в итоге все наоборот
как мне это исправить?

такая же ситуация, пока не понял в чем дело

А если imagemin убрать?

я пробовал оставить только перенос и всеравно они перемещаются битыми, в 4 версии такого не происходит, сегодня почему то скачался gulp 5 и вместе с ним появилась такая проблема const images = () => { return gulp.src("app/img/**/*").pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')) }

Да я тоже пробывал убрать imagemin, была такая же проблема.
Сначала думал что картинка битая скачалась, но оказалось что нет. пробывал разные методы, не фига психанул и откатил до версии 4.0.2 :D

Тоже такая проблема с картинками  imagemin тут не причем. Видимо подключение с картинками и путями изменили в самом галпе ,нужно будет теперь разбираться че там они намутили такого.

решил проблему , нужно применить опцию { encoding: false } непосредственно к вызову функции src(). Это сообщает Gulp не конвертировать данные в текстовую кодировку. Пример в моем случае :
    return src('app/images/**/*.*', { encoding: false })

Дальше уже идут ваши настройки
